# using healthkit in application

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm working on a medical application for iOS and I really need to use Healthkit and integrate it with my app, but I don't have a developper account. What should I do please.

Answer (score 0):

(1) You need have a developer account

https://developer.apple.com

(2) You should know about HealthKit and you could know anything on the Apple's official documentation

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit#classes